# How it exactly works?

Tags: bash

I was trying to install Node.js on Ubuntu 16.04 with the help of the following instruction

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -
```

I was confused to see `sudo "bash -"` without options specified. How it can be so?

Comment: `-` means to read by convention from stdin which is unnecessary here.

Comment: So I understand that so with | sudo bash without "-" it should work?

Comment: Yes, it should work without `-`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command line uses `curl` to download a script from Node's site. It then pipes it in to a new shell executed as root (thanks to the `sudo`), and the script contains all the actions required for installing Node.